# Use completeFileProtection on UserDefaults.standard.data in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am following the guide at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/encrypting_your_app_s_files
and I was wondering if is possible/ how can I use completeFileProtection in a note app that stores the notes in UserDefaults.standard.data:

```
@State var items: [NoteItem] = {
    guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "notes" ) else { return [] }
    if let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode([NoteItem].self, from: data) {
        return json
    }
    return []
}()
```

If completeFileProtection is not applicable to standard.data what is the default behaviour of this data? e.g if the app is protected with FaceID/Biometrics what protection will standard.data have based on the classification at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/encrypting_your_app_s_files ?

Comment: From what I understand UserDefaults is the most public part of an app and as a best practice should only be used for stuff like preferences and minor settings. I highly doubt there are any protections for what is stored there. Plus, I’m pretty sure I’ve heard people say that Apple has reset UserDefaults during updates, probably not on purpose but I have seen it mentioned here before.

Comment: https://www.donnywals.com/deciding-where-to-store-data/

Comment: @loremipsum thanks for the info, should I then change to a json file? could you provide a working example using a file e.g. in Documents folder?

Comment: I would use CoreData there are a ton of examples out there about that and XCode gives you a really good starting point when you create a new project with CoreData. I would even make it compatible with CloudKit so the user can get their notes on any device. You can store anything there and once you have a Persistence Manager setup it is seamless. But if you want to stick with JSON I’m sure you can find questions on SO and tutorials online.

Comment: I think the best solution is this https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper easy to modify UserDefault with this wrapper

Comment: Go for it give it a try but using 3rd party products is inherently dangerous. Make sure you know what is going on. I don't know anything bout this particular one so I don't mean that they are inherently nefarious but it seems like every other day there is an article about some research company identifying some common 3rd party product in GitHub as being a vulnerability. If you truly need security like keychain I would recommend you understand the product, the Apple documentation and how everything works before depending on a 3rd party product.